# Mahalanobis distance - vectors orientation?

Tags: r, metric

In the Mahalanobis distance there are both $(\vec{x}-\vec{y})^T$ and $(\vec{x}-\vec{y})$. Which one is a column vector and which one is row vector? I need to write this in R, so vector orientation is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(\vec{x}-\vec{y})^T$ is the row vector. Only then the matrix multiplication is feasible.

Answer (score 0):

With S as your covariance matrix, the R code would be the following:

```
d <- sqrt(t(x-y) %*% solve(S) %*% (x-y))
```

Vectors are typically assumed to be column vectors.

Comment: My vectors are rows cut from matrix like mat[i,]. Therefore I should have ```sqrt((x-y) %*% solve(S) %*% t(x-y))```?

Comment: I tried it in R, and it seems to be converting mat[i,] to a column vector, meaning that your code does not work. I was expecting yours to work, since mat[i,] is a row vector, but R seems to change them to column vectors.

Comment: That's interesting, thank you.